# How would you maximize Kassadin's laning phase before he hits level 6

Tags: league-of-legends

How would you do well in the laning fase when playing Kassadin before he becomes level 6? We all know that Kassadin is one of the strongest and most flexible champions after he hits level 6, but it's definitely a pain trying to get creepkills in earlier levels. Would you generally use your Q to last hit like Gangplanks Parley?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use general early game farming techniques, like walking back and forth on the edge of the enemies attack range. You can fake some moves so you can grab a few creepkills when not expected. Also, farming up with Q is indeed often used.

You can try and farm up a Tear of the Goddess as fast as you can, so you can spam your skills and use that to farm. Try to figure out per game if it is more profitable to use your spells on the enemy and force him to back out or miss some creepkills, or use them to get some creepkills.

Always try to melee lasthit the creep if you think you will survive and won't lose too many hitpoints. Else, just sit it out and farm under your tower untill level 6. Remember, two hits from a turret on a melee creep leaves him with so little hp that every champion can lasthit that creep.

Comment: mind that the creeps who def the turret will also attack enemy creep, which makes lasthitting much more complicated. also a very pressuring and nukey opponent (annie, elise, lee sin) can still burst you down under your turret

Comment: That is correct. A general tip is still to NOT attack the creeps under your turret, unless you feel heavely pressured. When you see such situation coming, make it very clear to the jungler or other lane that you need help and that the jungler, or a lane pushing, should come and help you! Doesn't matter if they are seen, if they scare the enemy away they will lose on xp and you know there is a ward there. Counterward it with pink (money is returned by destroying the ward).

Comment: @Joetjah I'd just like to comment about farming under the turret.  Kassadin has very slow waveclear, so it's quite likely that you will be pushed to your turret at some point in time in the game.  Turret damage is pretty static, (melee minions take two hits, then you can last hit them, casters - AA-turret hit-AA for the last hit).  You should master farming at your turret.  It's safe there, and leaves the enemy mid open for an easy gank.  It's not bad to farm under your turret.  Try and find a video of TheRainMan playing kassadin: You could learn alot by watching him.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I just came up of a response to @Vogel612 , I don't think those champions will nuke you down under the turret. After that, you are level 6 and it's a whole different story.

Comment: Counterquestion: How do you avoid being nuked under your turret, given the case your HP is < 400 and your enemy is some diver/nuker, without losing loads of farm (and thus gold) or going back? also: How can you be sure you will not be dived and nuked down?? i have seen an awful lot of mid-players feeling safe under their turret with 500+ HP and a single gank + dive on lvl 4 killed them (heca from behind and annie in mid or some similar combo)

Comment: A silence, slow and HP potion do more than you think on that level range.

Comment: ye... a silence for flash-incinerate annie after hecarim sprint and q, a slow for a non-focused target (as no damage on you yet) and an ignite on you... you are most certainly dead.

Comment: If Hecarim is on your team and you dive on Annie, you hit her with Q to silence her casting and Flash, then you hit her with your slow. On those levels, it's an almost certain death. Don't try to find examples like this because they work both ways. Before level 4, you usually don't get ganked, and afterwards, I hope you've got a Tear and/or perhaps a friendly gank or 2 from your jungler.

Comment: @Vogel612 there's a million situations I can think of to help illustrate either my point or yours.  No strategy is perfect.  Have you seen their jungle lately? Has Annie been showing signs of aggression? If that's the case, maybe you should waste all of your mana ASAP to waveclear and go back. If you think they are gonna dive, be safe and go B.  If she has been playing passive, try to tough it out and farm under your turret, and ask your jungler for a gank. Try running teleport instead of Ignite. Sure Ignite will help you secure a few kills, but TP could help you secure Barons/dragons

Comment: @Joetjah btw i didn't mean to single you out in my last comment to you: I meant ANYONE could learn from watching TRM play Kassadin :)

Comment: I know man, TRM and his hat rock!

Comment: but dat laugh o.o